# Simple inference example tflite + kotlin

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to adapt a [simple example](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/posenet/android/posenet/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/posenet/lib/Posenet.kt) of tflite and android.

```
val inputArray = arrayOf(initInputArray(bitmap))
val outputMap = initOutputMap(getInterpreter())
getInterpreter().runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap)
```

Since my model only has one output. I change the outputMap into an outputArray

```
val inputArray = arrayOf(initInputArray(bitmap))
val outputArray = Array(1){ Array(height) { Array(width) { FloatArray( channels }}}
getInterpreter().run(inputArray, outputArray)
```

However when feeding it to the inference method I get:

```
DataType error: cannot resolve DataType of [Ljava.nio.ByteBuffer;
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error:

```
val inputArray = arrayOf(initInputArray(bitmap))
```

was the culprit. When using `run` instead of `runForMultipleInputsOutputs` this cannot be an array! So changing the line to

```
val inputArray = initInputArray(bitmap)
```

fixes the issue.

A good documentation of the required data formats would have helped...

- run -> requires "DirectByteBuffer" as input
- runForMultipleInputsOutputs -> requires "ByteBuffer" as input